# Make a random dispersion of images

Tags: gimp, inkscape, images, transform, technique

I got a lot of unique images, so my goal is distribute all that images randomly and apply randomly scale and rotation transformations.

Like these
[image]

So which is the best way to achieve these ? I use gimp and inkscape but if you know a way using another editor like AI o PS i would like to hear it

Comment: Often you need a bit of programming to do this I think. But if you have _Imagemagick_ around, this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#layer_prog) and this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) may provide a direction for some scripting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with sculpt/painting [image]

Just move your objects in random directions, shrink/enlarge and rotate [image]

Example of the result:

[image]

Comment: nice aproximation